# Vimeo embedded videos in Angular

Tags: angular, vimeo

When I use a Vimeo video in my application, it first shows my page inside the container and after it's the moment it loads the video. In safari when the Vimeo request fails, the user is capable to navegate inside the container. It's like an inception feeling. Do you know how to make only load the video and not my page?

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the embed code?

Comment: Are you embedding the video using the Vimeo embed code, or are you simply embedding the vimeo.com/[video_id] page? Please provide more details.